# Google Apps Script return image in doGet function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am unable to figure out how to return an image in Google Apps Script. I've also gone through a lot of documentation and am unable to find anything clear.

In PHP, the equivalent function would be:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61\x1\x0\x1\x0\x80\x0\x0\xfc\x6a\x6c\x0\x0\x0\x2c\x0\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0\x1\x0\x0\x2\x2\x44\x1\x0\x3b";
```

I've tried functions like:

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61\x1\x0\x1\x0\x80\x0\x0\xfc\x6a\x6c\x0\x0\x0\x2c\x0\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0\x1\x0\x0\x2\x2\x44\x1\x0\x3b");
}
}
```

But it does not seem to work. I basically want to return a 1x1 pixel image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/) only supports returning plain text, ATOM, CSV, iCal, JavaScript, JSON, RSS, vCard, and XML content.

It depends on your user case, but you can use [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) and the data URI scheme to embed an image:

**GS:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
  </body>
</html>
```

Also you can use HTML5 and Canvas:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
```

Or JavaScript to create a gif